# Angular Square box layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm trying to achieve a square grid layout using css on ng-repeat items

Basically I need a Big square following with 4 small squares this 4 small sqares in sum have the same width and height as big square.

My CSS:

```
.container{
  width: 1398px;
}
.item{
            float: left;
            margin: 3px;
            overflow: hidden;

            width: 460px;
            height: 460px;
            background-color:black;
        }
        .item:nth-of-type(2n),
        .item:nth-of-type(3n),
        .item:nth-of-type(4n),
        .item:nth-of-type(5n) {
            width: 227px;
            height: 227px; 
        }
        .item:nth-of-type(4n){
            margin-left: -230px;
            margin-top: 236px;
        }
        .item:nth-of-type(5n){
            margin-left: -463px;
            margin-top: 236px;
        }
```

Everything works but after 5th element grid breaks

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/enq1okge/4/

Comment: P.S: 5th is inaccurate. It depends on what screen size you're looking :)

Comment: Have you tried to search for / seen this?: https://github.com/passy/angular-masonry

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I've updated my question with fixed container. I don't want to include all this libriries. It seems like solution should be simple.

Comment: I don't think what you are looking for is achievable with pure css.
I know about [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-masonry)

Comment: @OmriLuzon Thank you for your link But I've all seen, I'm looking for something simple with 2 size boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct css is

```
.cont{
  width: 1398px;
}
.item{
  float: left;
  margin: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background:#000;
  width: 227px;
  height: 227px; 
  background-color:black;
}
.item:nth-of-type(5n + 1) {
  background-color:red;
  width: 460px;
  height: 460px;
}
.item:nth-of-type(5n - 1){
  margin-left: -230px;
  margin-top: 236px;
}
.item:nth-of-type(5n){
  margin-left: -463px;
  margin-top: 236px;
}
```

Working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/enq1okge/7/)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to work out some `nth-child` trickery. Although not a bullet-proof solution, it could be a possible workaround if you do not want to depend on a third-party library.

Broad idea is to clear the float on every 1st, 6th, 11th, 16th.. and so on elements, and make the size approximately twice as much as others. Depending on the container's width you will have to work it out carefully.

In this case, it will be `:nth-child(5n+1)`. Once you've figured that out, proceed to size those elements. For the bigger one, let it take approx half the width of container i.e. `container-width / 2`. For the rest, make them a quarter i.e. `container-width / 4`.

Here is a crude example **snippet**:

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
div.cont { 
 width: 80vw; clear: both; margin: 8px auto;
}
div.item { 
 float: left;
 background-color: #33e; margin: 1px;
 width: calc((80vw / 4) - 4px); height: calc((80vw / 4) - 4px);
}
div.item:nth-child(5n+1) {
 width: calc((80vw / 2) - 6px); height: calc((80vw / 2) - 6px);
 background-color: #e33; clear: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont clearfix">
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

And a fiddle for you to play with: **: https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/95rx53o6/**

**Note**: Keeping the container's size in percent or viewport relative units and then calculating the children's size based on that, will allow you to keep it responsive.